# Cross-references Showing Part Number

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there a way to make cross references write `\part` number like this?

Cf. above **Part 1**, Page 3.

I am currently using: `\here{}\label{}` and `\footnote{Cf. \where{}. Page \pageref{}.}`

So I need something that would check in which part the label is and than write the number of that part in the footnote.

Edit: I thought that is not important re `\where` and `\here` but I am adding code for that as requested.

```
\makeatletter
\newcount\here@undef
\newcommand{\here}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{}{\global\advance\here@undef by -1}%
  \global\@namedef{here@#1}{}%
}
\newcommand{\where}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{here@#1}{%
    below%
    \@ifundefined{here@#1@undef}{%
      \global\@namedef{here@#1@undef}{}%
      \global\advance\here@undef by 1
    }{}%
  }{%
    above%
  }%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifnum\here@undef>0
    \GenericWarning{}{There were undefined above/below labels}%
  \fi}
\makeatother%
```

Comment: I think this is some job for `zref` and `refcount` ...

Comment: How or where are the `\here` and `\where` macros defined? Which document class do you use? Do you load any cross-referencing packages?

Comment: I use scrbook and hyperref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `zref` is made for such tasks: Extraction of label data, if the relevant `\zlabel` etc. commands are used.

In order to provide the correct information, a 'property' has to be stored, in this case the property is the part number which should be connected to the label.

The command `\here` stores the label with the given name using `\zlabel@byprops` and `\there` extracts the information later on.

**Update** Version with working hyperlinks:

```
 \documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[counter,user,hyperref]{zref}




\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
}{
  \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
  \providecommand{\hyperlink}[2]{#2}
}

\zref@newlist{partpage}
\zref@newprop*{partprop}[-1]{\number\value{part}}
\zref@addprops{partpage}{partprop,page,anchor} % page is defined by default!

\newcounter{herecntr}

\newcommand{\here}[1]{%
  \phantomsection% Needed for correct hyper links
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{partprop,page,anchor}%
}

\newcommand{\there}[1]{%
  Part \zref[partprop]{#1}, page \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zpageref{#1}}
}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
Now, let us see\footnote{You will find in \there{firstref} some important information, but in \there{secondref} the information is much more important. Give it a try, but do not forget the stuff in \there{somethingdifferent}}


\part{My wonderful first part} 

\blindtext[6] firstref\here{firstref}

\part{My second and yet better part}

\blindtext[7] secondref\here{secondref}


\part{My third and yet even better part}

\blindtext[3] thirdref\here{thirdref}

\chapter{Foo}\here{somethingdifferent}

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** With compressed references, i.e. the `\there` command does not print the part number if the reference is in the same part!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[counter,user,hyperref]{zref}




\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
}{
  \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
  \providecommand{\hyperlink}[2]{#2}
}

\zref@newlist{partpage}
\zref@newprop*{partprop}[-1]{\number\value{part}}
\zref@addprops{partpage}{partprop,page,anchor} % page is defined by default!

%\newcounter{herecntr}

\newcommand{\here}[1]{%
  \phantomsection% Needed for correct hyper links
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{partprop,page,anchor}%
}

\newcommand{\there}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{part}=\zref@extract{#1}{partprop}\relax% Check whether the current part counter value is the same as the extracted part property from the label
  page \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zpageref{#1}}
  \else% No, it is not the same!
  Part \zref[partprop]{#1}, page \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zpageref{#1}}%
  \fi
}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\part{My wonderful first part} 

Now, let us see\footnote{You will find in \there{firstref} some important information, but in \there{secondref} the information is much more important. Give it a try, but do not forget the stuff in \there{somethingdifferent}}



\blindtext[6] firstref\here{firstref}

\part{My second and yet better part}

\blindtext[7] secondref\here{secondref}


\part{My third and yet even better part}

\blindtext[3] thirdref\here{thirdref}

\chapter{Foo}\here{somethingdifferent}

\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @eklisiarh: You're welcome! Happy TeXing

Comment: Is it posible to slightly modify this so that in case the footnote is in the part in which is referenced it produces different output? For example if the footnote is in part 1 and cross reference is also in part 1 it produces just "Cf. P. 3" but if the footnote is in part 2 it produces "Cf. part 2, page 3."?

Comment: @eklisiarh: You mean 'compressed' references? I think, this is possible

Comment: @eklisiarh: See the update at the bottom of the answer

Comment: The updated version works perfectly in the MWE but doesn't in my file. I must find out why and if I do I will get back to you. Tx.