# How to show also the name of the parent counter with cleveref?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, cleveref

Consider the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \section{Section One.One}
  \label{mysection}
  \lipsum

  \section{Section One.Two}
  Please ignore \cref{mysection}.

  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \section{Section Two.One}

  As you may have noticed, \cref{mysection} is useless.
\end{document}
```

By default, in both uses of `\cref` I get `Section 1.1` as expected.

Is it possible to change the way the reference is shown in such a way that the *second* use of `\cref` above will print `Section 1 of Chapter 1`? i.e., naming the parent counter as well.

However, this should be done only *outside* the own chapter, so the first use of `\cref` in the above example should print `Section 1`.

This comes from a use case of a normative text where the document is divided in "articles" and "commas", and it is good to have references like "Comma 1 of Article 2" or "Article 2, Comma 1".

Comment: Does the recent posting [different labels for the same equation for choosing the appropriate one in different references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353197/5001) speak to your posting as well? Please advise.

Comment: This is difficult with `cleveref`, I think. Apart from Mico's link, see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346918/cross-references-showing-part-number (also an answer by me)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer zref would be the ideal solution, but the information about the parent is kept already by cref I think. Can one get the parent counter of a counter?

Comment: @gigabytes: I am working on a solution right now ;-) It's easy if a counter has only one parent counter (this most time the case)

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable assumption :)

Comment: @gigabytes: Take a look ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 2017/03/05 at the end**

**Update 2017/06/07: Similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373769/31729**

Determining the parent counter of a counter is easy, if there is only one parent counter, so this is a unique mapping then.

I stored all counters being defined at the begin of the document in a sequence and 'cracked' the `\cl@X` list (`X` being a driver counter name, such as, say, `chapter`), storing their content into a property list which contains the parent counter.

The `\getparentcounter` macro can be used to retrieve the value.

Now the `zref` package stores the properties `childcountervalue`, `parentcountervalue` and `parentcountername` in order to retrieve them later with `\zref@extract`.

The anchor is stored as well, just in case we're using `hyperref`.

The macros `\parentcref` and `\parentCref` will output the parent counter and the child counter with the first character in lower case (which is the counter name, actually) and the first character in upper case, i.e. `section → Section` etc.

The code assumes that the counters are using numbers only, i.e. `\arabic{foo}`. I'll try to remove this limitation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[user,counter,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{
\newif\if@hyperrefloaded

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \@hyperrefloadedtrue
}{
  \@hyperrefloadedfalse
}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{letltxmacro}



\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_latex_parentcounters_prop 
\seq_new:N  \g_latex_counters_seq

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn {Nx,cx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn {Nx,cx,No}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_tail:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_uppercase:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn {Nx,No}

% Store all reset lists and make a property list for each counter and its possible parent counter
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \GetAllResetLists {%
  \def\@elt##1{%
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_latex_counters_seq {##1}%
    \seq_new:c { g_latex_cntr_##1_seq }
  }
  \cl@@ckpt%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_latex_counters_seq {%
    \def\@elt####1{####1,}
    \seq_gset_from_clist:cx { g_latex_cntr_##1_seq } { \use:c{cl@##1} }
  }
  % Now fill the parent counter lists
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_latex_counters_seq {%
    \seq_map_inline:cn { g_latex_cntr_##1_seq }{ %
      \prop_gput:Nnn \g_latex_parentcounters_prop {####1} {##1}
    }
  }
}

% Gives the parent counter of a specific counter (or nothing)
\cs_new:Npn \getparentcounter #1{%
  \prop_item:No \g_latex_parentcounters_prop {#1}
}

% Make the first character of a word upper case
\newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]{%
  \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str {#1}%
  \str_uppercase:x {\str_head:N \l_tmpa_str}\str_tail:V {\l_tmpa_str}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\GetAllResetLists

\def\LastRefSteppedCounter{}

% Define new properties
\zref@newprop{childcountervalue}{\arabic{\LastRefSteppedCounter}}% This is the naked value
\zref@newprop{parentcountervalue}{\csname the\getparentcounter{\LastRefSteppedCounter}\endcsname}
\zref@newprop{parentcountername}{\getparentcounter{\LastRefSteppedCounter}}

% Add the new properties to the main property list stored with \zlabel
\zref@addprops{main}{childcountervalue,parentcountervalue,parentcountername}

\AtBeginDocument{%

  \LetLtxMacro\latex@@label\label
  \let\latex@@refstepcounterorig\refstepcounter

  \RenewDocumentCommand{\refstepcounter}{m}{%
    \global\xdef\LastRefSteppedCounter{#1}%
    \latex@@refstepcounterorig{#1}%
  }
  %Make the ordinary label and a \zlabel
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\label}{om}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
      \latex@@label[1]{#2}%
    }{%
      \latex@@label{#2}%
    }%
    \zlabel{#2}%
  }%
}

% Command for uppercase output
\NewDocumentCommand{\parentCref}{m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \Cref{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\@tmpb@{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \edef\@tmpa@{\csname the\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}\endcsname}%
    \ifx\@tmpb@\@tmpa@
    \Cref{#1}%
    \else
    \if@hyperrefloaded
    \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue}} of \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \else
    \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}} \zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue} of \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}} \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}%
    \fi
    \fi
  }%
}

% Command for lowercase output
\NewDocumentCommand{\parentcref}{m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \cref{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\@tmpb@{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \edef\@tmpa@{\csname the\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}\endcsname}%
    \ifx\@tmpb@\@tmpa@
    \Cref{#1}%
    \else
    \if@hyperrefloaded
    \zref@extract{#1}{counter} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue}} of \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \else
    \zref@extract{#1}{counter} \zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue} of \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername} \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}%
    \fi
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter One}
  Please look at \parentCref{othersection} or at \parentCref{foosubsection} or at \parentcref{foosubsection}


  \section{Section One.One}
  \label{mysection}
  \lipsum

  \section{Section One.Two}

  \subsection{A subsection} \label{foosubsection}
  Please ignore \parentCref{mysection}.

  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \section{Section Two.One}

  As you may have noticed, \parentCref{mysection} is useless.


  \chapter{Chapter Three}
  \section{Section Three.One}
  \section{Section Three.Two}\label{othersection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [Renumbering chapter after part, include part number as suffix in cross-reference to chapter number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356248/renumbering-chapter-after-part-include-part-number-as-suffix-in-cross-reference) for a similar question, but that's not a duplicate!

**Update 2017/03/06** Some features of this answer has been added to the `xassoccnt` v1.3 package (Download from [xassoccnt](http://www.ich-rede-mich-um-kopf-und-kragen.de/xassoccnt-v1-3-uploaded-to-ctan) until it is available on CTAN, TeXLive (since 2017/03/06) and MikTeX) The solution is much shorter now:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[user,counter,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{
  \newif\if@hyperrefloaded

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \@hyperrefloadedtrue
}{
  \@hyperrefloadedfalse
}
}
\makeatother




\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_latex_parentcounters_prop 
\seq_new:N  \g_latex_counters_seq

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_tail:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_uppercase:n {x,o,V}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_set:Nn {Nx,No}

% Store all reset lists and make a property list for each counter and its possible parent counter

% Make the first character of a word upper case
\newcommand{\FirstUpcase}[1]{%
  \str_set:Nx \l_tmpa_str {#1}%
  \str_uppercase:x {\str_head:N \l_tmpa_str}\str_tail:V {\l_tmpa_str}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff




% Define new properties
\zref@newprop{childcountervalue}{\arabic{\LastRefSteppedCounter}}% This is the naked value
\zref@newprop{parentcountervalue}{\csname the\GetParentCounter{\LastRefSteppedCounter}\endcsname}
\zref@newprop{parentcountername}{\GetParentCounter{\LastRefSteppedCounter}}

% Add the new properties to the main property list stored with \zlabel
\zref@addprops{main}{childcountervalue,parentcountervalue,parentcountername}

% Command for uppercase output
\NewDocumentCommand{\parentCref}{m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \Cref{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\@tmpb@{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \edef\@tmpa@{\csname the\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}\endcsname}%
    \ifx\@tmpb@\@tmpa@
    \Cref{#1}%
    \else
    \if@hyperrefloaded
    \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue}} of \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \else
    \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{counter}} \zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue} of \FirstUpcase{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}} \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}%
    \fi
    \fi
  }%
}

% Command for lowercase output
\NewDocumentCommand{\parentcref}{m}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \cref{#1}%
  }{%
    \edef\@tmpb@{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \edef\@tmpa@{\csname the\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername}\endcsname}%
    \ifx\@tmpb@\@tmpa@
    \Cref{#1}%
    \else
    \if@hyperrefloaded
    \zref@extract{#1}{counter} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue}} of \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername} \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}}%
    \else
    \zref@extract{#1}{counter} \zref@extract{#1}{childcountervalue} of \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountername} \zref@extract{#1}{parentcountervalue}%
    \fi
    \fi
  }%
}

\makeatother


\GetAllResetLists
\RegisterPostLabelHook{\zlabel}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
  Please look at \parentCref{othersection} or at \parentCref{foosubsection} or at \parentcref{foosubsection}


  \section{Section One.One}
  \label{mysection}
  \lipsum

  \section{Section One.Two}

  \subsection{A subsection} \label{foosubsection}
  Please ignore \parentCref{mysection}.

  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \section{Section Two.One}

  As you may have noticed, \parentCref{mysection} is useless.


  \chapter{Chapter Three}
  \section{Section Three.One}   %
  \section{Section Three.Two}\label{othersection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico: It's a counter - related question... don't expect too much ;-) But thanks! (The usual complainers will show up soon ;-))

Comment: That does indeed what I needed! I'm not at all familiar with the expl3 syntax. What is going on more precisely?

Comment: @gigabytes: I will explain later on, alright? The expl3 way is just used to make a simplified storage of the bunch of data (the counter names, here) and easy access of data -- you can think of a `\prop_....` list like a hash array, where a key has a value, here the counter name is key and its value is its parent counter. The other content is rather string uppercase related. One could bypass this by using another `\prop_....` list but it would have to be done manually, most likely

Comment: @Mico: See the bunch of upvotes :D :D

Comment: It's nevertheless a great answer. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. Do you think it is useful to cast it into some package? I am thinking of extending my `xassoccnt` with reference features

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - What's really difficult is to gauge the demand for such a feature. Speaking for myself, I find it discouraging that there's been only very limited uptake to date of the `zref` package. Of course, this may be because the machinery of the `zref` package is, on the whole, rather very "low level" and doesn't lend itself easily to adoption by "end users", i.e., the "average" writer of a LaTeX-based document. If you can figure out how to provide a straightforward front end, which hides the programming complexity, from end users, some end users might actually start using it.

Comment: @Mico: The `zref` package is brilliant in its technique, but its main downside is the splitting between `\label` and `\zlabel` or the explicit need of `\label@byprops` etc. If it would hijack `\label` completely, many tasks could be simplified, but of course, this would break other `\label/\ref` related packages. I'll think about it