# Get both the chapter and section of a referenced section

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I have chapters numbered with roman numerals and sections numbered with arabic numbers (starting from 1 for each new section, *i.e.* section I.3, section II.3, section III.3 - and so on - are all just displayed as "section 3").

I had to format my thesis in this way to comply to the guidelines of the Faculty and I did that by including these line in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capitolo}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

Yet, given that - for example - section II.3 is labelled `\label{sec:chap2sec3}`, I'd like to have in the text something like "see section II.3" when in the code I write "see section `\ref{sec:chap2sec3}` (instead of just "see section 3" as I get at the moment).

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Package `\cleveref` and `\cref{sec:chap2sec3}`, but your labelling scheme is not really useful, in my point of view. As soon as the order of your sections etc. change sec3 isn't sec3 any longer.

Comment: Seee also for an example of more sophisticated approaches: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353491/how-to-show-also-the-name-of-the-parent-counter-with-cleveref

Comment: Apparently I'm confused about something.  Does "external pressures" mean "must have chapters numbered with roman numerals and sections numbered with arabic numbers"?  Or does "external pressures" mean "must have these three specific lines in the preamble"?  Or something else?

Comment: @teepeemm I edit the text, hope it's clearer now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the quick and dirty method, by changing the `\p@section` reference  formatting macro to be prepended with `\thechapter.` and combining it with `cleveref`.

Note: `\setcounter{section}{100}` is just for testing purposes.

```
\documentclass{book}


\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capitolo}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

See \cref{Foosection} for more information

\chapter{Other chapter}

\chapter{Foo} 

\setcounter{section}{100}
\section{Foo section} \label{Foosection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** The version without `cref`

```
\documentclass{book}


\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capitolo}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@section}{\thechapter.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See \ref{Foosection} for more information

\chapter{Other chapter}

\chapter{Foo} 

\setcounter{section}{100}
\section{Foo section} \label{Foosection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this over `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}`?

Comment: @Teepeemm: You will find the reason in the question. Don't blame me for requests done by O.P. or thesis boards or whatever ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks very much! I don't understand the need for the "\setcounter{section}{100}" line: infact, what I wanted is best achieved by eliminating it. Only problem is that, instead of e.g. "I.3", "section I.3" is displayed when I write "\cref{label:chap2sec3}". How can I eliminate the word "section"?

Comment: @luciadefinetti: The `\setcounter{section}{100}` was just for testing purposes. And your question says `see section II.3` ... so `\cref{...}` does explicitly add the word `section` to it. If you don't need this, don't write `see section II.3` in your question ;-) Replace `\cref` by the ordinary `\ref` then.

Comment: Thanks very much @ChristianHupfer and, yes, my mistake! :-)

Comment: I was reading "external pressures" as "must have Roman chapters and arabic sections", and OP included those lines to satisfy them.

Comment: Even if "external pressures" means "must have those three lines", OP could still `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}` later on.  Unless I'm misunderstanding "find the reason in the question".