# Why \secref command in memoir with cleveref and nomencl no longer works

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, cleveref, incompatibility, nomencl

The document below, with a chapter/section scheme in a memoir class document, uses a custom `\secref` command. This command allows reference to a section in the shorter form "section s" that would normally appear in the full form "section c.s". Here c is the chapter number and s is the section number.

The `\secref` command is as kindly provided by Christian Hupfer, from his "trickier" code answer in [Reference with just part of section number after decimal point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383606/reference-with-just-part-of-section-number-after-decimal-point).

This document used to compile without error.

But now instead it gives this error:

```
./secref-try.tex:40: Use of \@stripdot doesn't match its definition.
<argument> 1
            .2
l.40 In section \secref{sec:more}
                              %% ERROR WITH \@stripdot here
```

Here is the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}  

%% NOTATION INDEX
\usepackage[nocfg]{nomencl}

%%%%%%%%  BEGIN CROSS-REFERENCING COMMANDS  %%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=red}

% Added to allow ref to section n, not section m.n
%    ``trickier' 'code by Christian Hupfer, from
%   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383606/reference-with-just-part-of-section-number-after-decimal-point
\makeatletter
\let\@xp\expandafter
% Stripping the dot from the 1.2 -like reference
\def\@@stripdot#1.#2\@nil{#2}
% Stripping the memoir stuff from the reference, 
%    i.e. \M@TitleReference {1.2}{FOO} and handing #1 (1.2) over to the \@@stripdot macro
\def\@stripdot\M@TitleReference #1#2\@nil{\@@stripdot#1\@nil}
% Macro, second level of expansion
\newcommand{\stripdot}[1]{%
  \@xp\@stripdot#1\@nil
}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
% Expand the argument first
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{%
  % Do nothing if #1 is not defined
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}{\@xp\stripdot\@xp{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize]{cleveref}

%%%%%%%%  END CROSS-REFERENCING COMMANDS  %%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

In section \secref{sec:more} %% ERROR WITH \@stripdot here
of \cref{chap:one} \dots .

And in \cref{sec:one} \dots .

\chapter{One}\label{chap:one}

  \section{About one}\label{sec:one}

  \section{More about one}\label{sec:more}

\chapter{Two}

In section \ref{sec:more}

\end{document}
```

**The error does *not* occur if `\usepackage[nocfg]{nomencl}` is commented out!** Instead, it produces the expected output, including the following first page:

[image: Output from \secnum OK without nomencl package]

**Question:**

What's wrong?

Did something change recently in nomencl (which does have changes in version 5.1 dated 2019/02/08), cleveref, hyperref, or even memoir?

Comment: The code in the "Third installment" block of [Christian's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383608/5001) seems to work fine. Any reason for not using it?

Comment: @Mico: I *may* be able to use that "Third installment" instead, but with my actual, book-length project with many, many style modifications, I cannot tell whether doing so will create further problems. The issue remains as to why the "trickier" version no longer works!

Comment: There's nothing like giving the alternative code a try and find out if any "further problems" are created, right? Aside: Is there any particular reason to suspect that "further problems" *might* be created by the use of the code in the "third installment" block?

Comment: As I recall, Christian's "Third installment" uses `\xassoccnt`, which did not get along with `\calc` (and I do need `\calc`). Or was that package conflict fixed?

Comment: As of version 1.7 of `xassoccnt`, the `calc` package -- and any packages, such as `mathtools`, which depend on `calc` -- should be loaded *before* xasoccnt`.  Since the code insertion is slated to occur between loading the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages, this shouldn't be a meaningful restriction on your coding ambitions.

Comment: The `\@stripdot` is not by me and we 'talked' about this already, that `xassoccnt` should be loaded after any package that makes use of `calc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell you *why* the code in the "trickier" block of Christian Hupfer's answer doesn't work for you. However, as I already noted in a comment, the code in the "[third installment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383608/5001)" block of Christian's answer seems to work just fine.

(Note that the following code expects that version 1.5 or newer of the `xassoccnt` package is in use.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}  
\usepackage[nocfg]{nomencl}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 

%% The following code is from the 'third instalment' 
%% block of the answer posted by Christian Hupfer at 
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383608
\usepackage{xparse,xassoccnt}
\usepackage[user,hyperref]{zref}
\RegisterPostLabelHook{\zlabel}
\makeatletter
% Replace \arabic{section} with \Roman{section} etc. as needed:
\zref@newprop{section}{\arabic{section}} 
\zref@addprop{main}{section}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \ref{#1}}{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}%
       {\zref@extract{#1}{section}}}}
\makeatother
%% End of code from Christian Hupfer's answer

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
Section \secref{sec:two} of \cref{chap:one} 

\Cref{sec:two} of \cref{chap:one} 

Section \ref{sec:two} of \cref{chap:one} 


\chapter{One}\label{chap:one} \dots
\section{About one}\label{sec:one} \dots
\section{About two}\label{sec:two} \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works just fine, even with my actual book-length project (where xassoccnt is indeed loaded after calc and after packages that depend on calc). I'll wait a bit before accepting this viable answer in the hope that somebody will discover why nomencl now causes the problem with Christian's "trickier" version.